# Convert Created Time using Javascript FQL Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql

I am using Facebook FQL to get photos and the time when they were created. The problem is am getting the created time as some long integer value e.g. 1306776492.

Now I am unable to convert it to proper date time using javascript.

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a Date objects time with the `setTime` method.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1306776492*1000);
document.write(d);
```

returns

> Mon May 30 2011 20:28:12 GMT+0300 (FLE
>   Daylight Time)

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ANRcm/

If you want the date to be printed in a different format, just have a look at the other methods available for `Date()`